# Saving Radio Button Inputs into Array

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on a custom survey that is dynamically populated with database information and needs to be saved as an array. I can make everything work as it should except I would like to use a star rating system for many of the answers and it seems radio buttons won't work like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[]" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[]" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[]" value="5" />
```

Because there are multiple instances of this same code. This will be saved into an array so `surveyRating` will be used over and over again. If I click a radio button in one group, it changes to a radio in another group.

I have read I can possibly do this with checkboxes instead. Is that the best alternative? Or is there another option I should be looking at? I want the final product to be star ratings 1-5. Not sure if I can do that with checkboxes.

**EDIT**

Ok so using `name="surveyRating[1]"` is helping as far as the radio buttons not conflicting on the client side. However, it is not saving correctly the way I have my php set up now. Here is how it is saved currently. What do I need to change to make the `[1]` work appropriately. Currently it is only saving the last iteration.

```
$new = array();
$ratings = $_POST['surveyRating'];
$count = count( $ratings );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
  if ( $ratings[$i] != '' ) {
    $new[$i]['surveyRating'] = stripslashes( strip_tags( $ratings[$i] ) );
  }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

So to demonstrate how I accomplished this using the answer below, I had to add [0] as the first iteration in the loop. I was using `$items = 0;` `$items++` to dynamically add a number to each loop.

To make it start at 0, I set `$items = -1` that way the first iteration is 0 instead of 1. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, it does because you have the name with `[]`. That's for array. Remove it and you will get it without array:

```html
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating" value="5" />
```

For radio buttons with several groups, you have to do something like this:

```html
<!-- Group 1 -->
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[1]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[1]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[1]" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[1]" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[1]" value="5" />

<!-- Group 2 -->
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[2]" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[2]" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[2]" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[2]" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="surveyRating[2]" value="5" />
```

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. I will be saving these like so: `$ratings = $_POST['surveyRating'];` so it NEEDS to be an array.

Comment: see my edit above, I am now unable to save my results.

Comment: @RiotAct What do you get when you do `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: `Array ( [surveyTalk] => Array ( [0] => Test [1] => Test Title ) [surveyRating] => Array ( [1] => 2 [2] => 1 )` the survey ratings should be connected with the survey talks in the way I have it set up.

Comment: Yes it is skipping ahead to [1] instead of [0] and the array objects don't match up because of it.

Comment: Ah! that makes sense. I'll try that.

Comment: Yep that was it! I will edit my question to show what I changed.

Comment: @RiotAct Happy for you! 